# how to access nargs of optparse-add_action?

Tags: python, python-2.7, optparse

I am working on one requirement for my project using command line utility:optparse.

Suppose if I am using add_option utility like below:

```
parser.add_option('-c','--categories', dest='Categories', nargs=4 )
```

I wanted to add `check` for `-c` option if user does not input 4 arguments.

**something like this:**

```
if options.Categories is None:
   for loop_iterate on nargs:
        options.Categories[loop_iterate] = raw_input('Enter Input')
```

How to access nargs of add_option().?

PS:I do not want to have check using `print.help()` and do `exit(-1)`

Please somebody help.

Comment: With that `option` entering `'-c 1 2 3'`, will produce an error `'error: -c option requires 4 arguments'` and exit.  Is that what you were expecting or want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK `optparse` doesn't provide that value in the public API via the result of `parse_args`, but you don't need it.
You can simply name the constant before using it:

```
NUM_CATEGORIES = 4

# ...

parser.add_option('-c', '--categories', dest='categories', nargs=NUM_CATEGORIES)

# later

if not options.categories:
    options.categories = [raw_input('Enter input: ') for _ in range(NUM_CATEGORIES)]
```

In fact the `add_option` method returns the `Option` object which does have the [`nargs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#optparse.Option.nargs) field, so you could do:

```
categories_opt = parser.add_option(..., nargs=4)

# ...

if not options.categories:
    options.categories = [raw_input('Enter input: ') for _ in range(categories_opt.nargs)]
```

However I really don't see how this is better than using a costant in the first place.

Comment: Yes as of now I will go by your first method. Suppose in future, if there is need/situation that, nargs needed to be updated from user input. how to get that one done. Updated the same in question. please help me get that one done.thanks

Comment: I have raised necessary one which i mentioned in edit section as separate question @: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287279/how-to-modify-nargs-of-optparse-add-option-from-user-inputraw-input#
please somebody answer