# how to modify nargs( of optparse-add_option) from User input(raw_input)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, optparse

This Question is continuation of old question @: [how to access nargs of optparse-add_action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285311/how-to-access-nargs-of-optparse-add-action)

As that question was answered for what it was in-tented.

**Brief:**

Suppose if I am using add_option utility like below:

```
parser.add_option('-c','--categories', dest='Categories', nargs=4 )
```

Is there a way to modify `nargs` of `add_option()` from user input using `raw_input`.?

**EDIT:**
I will give a clear difference between my "previous question need" and "this question need".

*First question case:*

My script will ask for user inputs if user has provided no inputs, i.e.,He has just run

```
#./commandparser.py
```

*Second Question case requirement is:*

when i run my script ./commandparser.py -c abc bac cad
it throws error: `commandparser.py: error: -c option requires 4 arguments` and exit the script.

Instead of throwing error and exit the script. I want some mechanism so that it asks user to input remaining arguments i.e., 4th argument without exiting the script.

Comment: The other answer showed you that `nargs` is both a variable input to the `add_option` command, and a attribute of the object it returns.  Convert the `rawinput` to `int` and apply the value to either location.  But why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Normally `optparse` is used to handle the first thing the user gives the script - the command line values.  Sounds like you ask the user for some further input, and then parse the command line.  Wouldn't you rather get all the user input via the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you, by any chance, trying to accept a variable number of values for this option?  That is, use the 'rawinput' to set `nargs`, which is then used to parse the command line?

The `optparse` documentation has an example of using a custom callback to handle a variable number of values:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#callback-example-6-variable-arguments

`argparse`, on the other hand, does allow a variable number of values, with `nargs` values like '?' (0 or 1), '+' (1 or more), '*' (0 or more).

---

Since I'm more conversant with `argparse` I'll sketch out an interactive script to handle your revised requirement:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--categories', nargs='+', help='4 categories', default=[])
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
categories = args.categories
while len(categories)<4:
    print(parser.format_usage())
    x = raw_input('enter %s categories: '%(4-len(categories))).split()
    categories.extend(x)
print('categories', categories)
```

If 'categories' are the only arguments, you could replace all of the `argparse` stuff (or `optparse`) with `categories = sys.argv[1:]`, or `[2:]` if you still expect the `'-c'` flag.

---

Or using `optparse` (adapted from the docs example for variable length callback):

```
def vararg_callback(option, opt_str, value, parser):
     value = []
     for arg in parser.rargs:
         # stop on --foo like options
         if arg[:2] == "--" and len(arg) > 2:
             break
         # stop on -a (ignore the floats issue)
         if arg[:1] == "-" and len(arg) > 1:
             break
         value.append(arg)
     del parser.rargs[:len(value)]
     setattr(parser.values, option.dest, value)

def use_opt():
    import optparse
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option('-c','--categories', dest='categories', action="callback", callback=vararg_callback)
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    print options, args
    return options, args, parser

args, rest, parser = use_opt()
```

Comment: I have updated the question in edit segment, Please let know is it possible to resolve that problem with callback or any mechanism.?

Comment: I've added an `argparse` parser with interactive 'fill-in'.

Comment: My bad luck argparse is not working in my server, mine has 2.6.5 and i dont have permission to install python 3+

Comment: Are you, by any chance, trying to accept a variable number of values for this option? That is, use the 'rawinput' to set nargs, which is then used to parse the command line?


yes exactly this is what i need

Comment: To use `argparse`, all you need is one file, which you can grab from any py 2.7 source, and place in a local directory.

Comment: I've added an optparse variable length argument script.

Comment: okay, I will take yours optparse variable length argument script, now i wanted to access parser.values which has my variable , how to access it global to my python file.

Comment: I have been waiting for your response for quite a long time. please let me know how to access the variables from callback